# How can I get leveraged money

Tags: leverage

lets say I have 25k USD and I have found a good opportunity. how can I convert that 25k to 250k. This could be any investment not just Forex or ETF.

Comment: "leverage" refers to loaning money. If you can find somebody who would give you a loan of 225k you could leverage your 25k to 250k that's basically never going to happen

Comment: A mortgage is an example of this. People frequently put down 5 - 25% of the value of a house and borrow the rest from a bank.

Comment: FOREX is a good way to turn a 25K asset into a 250K liability.

Comment: Leverage is sort of a loan only. Go and ask any lender, if they will be willing to lend you that amount. 25-250 is quite an optimistic return. I doubt if the opportunity, if any, will be there for long.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, leveraged investing is investing borrowed money. To do so, you need to convince a lender that you're good for the loan. This usually means you need to have collateral worth what you're trying to borrow, or you need to pay a higher rate to account for the fact that they're gambling that you will remain employed and pay off the loan.

Leveraged investing is, in general, a risky move for exactly this reason. You can lose not just your original investment, but everything you borrowed as well.

The only time it really makes sense, in my admittedly conservative opinion, is when you (a) can afford to suffer that loss, (b) are pretty confident of your investment, and (c) have assets which you have no intention to sell for the duration of the loan. An "unneeded" mortgage on a house is a classic example, thusly:

When I purchased my house, I had enough savings that I could have bought it without taking a mortgage. Instead, I took out a mortgage for a large part of that, and left the remainder in my investment accounts -- essentially building the leveraging loan into the mortgage. I then got obscenely "lucky" when interest rates fell through the floor due to the Great Recession, and was able to refinance the mortgage to near record low rates. As a result, on that loan -- which, as I say, I'm in the position of being able to pay off at any time without killing my finances -- I'm currently paying about 3.5%, while the cash this has let me leave in my investments is earning several times that... a net win.

But again, note that this required collateral. Essentially, all I'm doing is paying a bit to to borrow my own money (part of the value of the house).

There really is no easy way to "convert 25k to 250k" -- if there was, everyone would be doing it.

There's no magic in investment. Just time and compounding returns and trading off risk against potential gain. The more you try to push it and win big, the more you risk losing big. I *really* recommend not attempting anything fancy until you're wealthy enough that you can afford those losses.

But if you insist on playing in this space, the answer to your question is to buy options. Options are a packaged form of borrowing to invest. Note that they're still considered high-risk unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing, and again I strongly recommend you not put money into them unless you can afford to lose it -- options have a nasty habit of turning from apparent gains on paper to losses remarkably quickly.